# Disable Source/Destination Check AWS Python Boto

Tags: boto

I am trying to automate deployment of a aws VPN [IPSec] instance using python boto. I am launching new instance using, 'ec2.run_instances'.

```
reservations = ec2.run_instances(
image_id,
subnet_id=subnet_id,
instance_type=instance_type,
instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior='stop',
key_name=key_name,
security_group_ids=[security_group])
```

For this script to work, I need to disable source/destination check for this instance. I couldn't find a way to disable this using python boto. As per the boto documentation I can do this using 'modify_instance_attribute'.

http://boto.likedoc.net/en/latest/ref/ec2.html

However I couldn't find any sample script using this attribute. Please give me some examples so that I can complete this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ec2 = boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection(region=regon)
ec2.modify_instance_attribute(instance.id, 'sourceDestCheck', 'false', dry_run=False)

Comment: code given above worked for me

Answer (score 2):

From [boto3 documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_instance_attribute) the way you would do this is:

```
response = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id')
instance_id = response.text
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
result = ec2_client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=instance_id, SourceDestCheck={'Value': False})
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the `modify_instance_attribute` method after you have launched the instance with `run_instances`.  Assuming your call to `run_instances` returns a single instance:

```
instance = reservations[0].instances[0]
ec2.modify_instance_attribute(instance.id, attribute='sourceDestCheck', value=False)
```