# How to put a NAT-Instance in auto scaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nat, aws-vpc

I wanted to create a fault tolerant website and was trying to create an autoscaling group.NAT-instance was used instead of NAT-Gateway. I experienced the following issues.

When a NAT instance gets terminated [for some reason].The auto-scaling group will launch the respective NAT image, but it would not have disabled the Source/destination check. That has to be done manually and as a result, the private subnet which is connected to the nat-instance will have the status message "Black-hole". Unless until the source destination check is manually changed, the private subnet won't even have the new NAT-instance displayed.

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Comment: When a NAT Instance goes down, it will leave all connections in limbo. Are your web-apps written so that they'll recover from timeouts when this happens, or will you need to restart them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the AWS CLI to modify the sourceDestCheck attribute of the network interface. You could launch this from the User Data of the instance. Other methods are a custom python program or even PowerShell (included below).

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-1234567890abcdef0 --source-dest-check "{\"Value\": true}"
```

Or by changing the network interace.

```
aws ec2 modify-network-interface-attribute --network-interface-id eni-686ea200 --no-source-dest-check
```

This Stack Overflow question covers doing the same in Python.

[Disable Source/Destination Check AWS Python Boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139271/disable-source-destination-check-aws-python-boto)

This document shows how to do this in PowerShell.

[Edit-EC2NetworkInterfaceAttribute Cmdlet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Edit-EC2NetworkInterfaceAttribute.html)

My preferred method would be Python or PowerShell. These methods are the easiest way to get the parameters that you need (instanceId or networkId).

[EDIT: Example programs]

Both examples below require either credentials installed on the instance or an IAM role. This is necessary to modify the source/destination flag.

Here is an example shell script.

```
EC2_INSTANCE_ID="`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`"
EC2_AVAIL_ZONE="`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`"
EC2_REGION="`echo \"$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE\" | sed -e 's:\([0-9][0-9]*\)[a-z]*\$:\\1:'`"
echo "Region:" $EC2_REGION

aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id $EC2_INSTANCE_ID --source-dest-check "{\"Value\": false}" --region $EC2_REGION

rc=$?; if [[ $rc != 0 ]]; then echo "Failure:" $rc; exit $rc; fi

echo "Success"
```

Here is an example Python 2 program using boto3 (change the region to yours):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3
import requests
import sys

# install boto3
# sudo pip install boto3

# Disable stack trace on failure
sys.tracebacklimit = 0

# Specify the URL for the instance metadata
url = 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id'

# Specify the region where our instance is at
region = 'us-west-2'

# Make a request to get the contents of the URL
r = requests.get(url)

if r.ok != True:
    print "Error: Failed to get instance-id from metadata:", r.reason
    print "Status Code:", r.status_code
    sys.exit(1)

# Get the instance ID from the return response
instance_id = r.text

print "Instance ID:", instance_id

if instance_id[0] != 'i':
    print "Error: Does not look like a valid instance ID: ", instance_id
    sys.exit(1)

client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

r = client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=instance_id, SourceDestCheck={'Value': False})

code = r['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']

if code != 200:
    print "Error: Cannot change SourceDestCheck: ", code
    sys.exit(1)

print "Success: SourceDestCheck disabled"
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I was about to try this option, but I have a question.The command what you have given has an instance ID, so in case if I am building a fault-tolerant website and wanted to automate the feature with auto-scaling [in case of some eventuality], will this command work? Coz if I input this in the user data, its tied to that particular instance and if I lose that instance this command will not work for the next instance which the auto scale provisions. 
Is there a command which I can input in user data which is instance independent?

Comment: I did not provide you with a complete solution, but rather how to achieve your objective. Create a batch script program. The EC2 instance metadata contains the instanceId. Get this value and then insert into your command line. Curl is often used to get the instanceId. This is why I recommend Python or PowerShell as all the steps are easier to implement.

Comment: Thank's John, meanwhile I was looking into the other links you had provided. The one from python boto3 had the below code. I think its close to what i was looking for.



"response = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id')
instance_id = response.text
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
result = ec2_client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=instance_id, SourceDestCheck={'Value': False})"

Comment: I updated my answer to include two examples. The first is a shell script which uses the AWS CLI, the second is a Python 2 program complete with error checking. My examples were tested on Amazon Linux.

Comment: you are the god to me :) Thanks for this. I will try this and keep this post updated

Comment: I tried both the options, the python boto one worked like a charm. The shell script did spin the instance but nothing changed. I checked the logs under /var/log/cloud-init-output.log.I didn't see any error messages. Anyhow, I was able to achieve what I wanted. Thanks a lot, John :)

Comment: If you run the shell script from the command line, what happens?

Comment: I didn't try that, so what you telling is 

1. Spin an instance 
2. Choose NAT from the AMI 
3. Don't input any data in the user data
4. Let the instance come up, No need to disable the source/destination check
5. Run the command in the CLI and it should disable the source /destination check automatically? 
will try this by evening and update this post

Comment: I tried it through the command prompt and it worked like a charm. When I was trying to add the script to the user data, i had made a mistake on the credentials. I need to work on my troubleshooting skills:) Thanks again John.

Comment: John, I have one more question with this, with the above script I was able to automate to a greater extent. But when the new NAT-Instance gets launched through autoscaling, the private subnet which is associated with the NAT instance doest gets associated with the new one. It says "black hole". I  have to manually associate the new NAT instance with the private subnet. I understand to avoid all these, I can choose a NAT-GATEWAY, but just to finetune my learning, I am curious about the same.

Comment: Create a new question for adding a NAT Gateway to a Route Table (specify Python or the tool of your choice).

Comment: Will definitely do that John. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [Instance Recovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html) rather than auto-scaling.  It replaces the instance without changing *anything* (even the instance ID remains the same).

Of course, in contrast to NAT instances, NAT Gateways are inherently fault-tolerant since they are not a single physical thing in a single physical place in the same sense that an instance is.